# How to execute bulk of groovy commands on slave node using pipeline code

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to convert free style job to pipeline as code. I have a bulk of following groovy commands that needs to run on slave nodes.

```
**stage ('Execute Groovy')**
def project = new XmlParser().parse( "target/checkout/pom.xml" )
def artifactID = project.artifactId.text()
def projectVersion = project.version.text()
def tag = "$artifactID-$projectVersion"
new File('release_info').text = "RELEASE_TAG=$tag\nRELEASE_VERSION=$projectVersion"
```

Error:

> "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /target/checkout/pom.xml (No such file
>   or directory)     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) "

I see from the output, groovy is executing on master (I know this is the nature of groovy) and couldn't figure out the file path and throwing error.

How to execute groovy commands on slave nodes using pipeline

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: How to you come to this conclusion:

> groovy is executing on master (I know this is the nature of groovy)

Comment: Ok, found this: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922508-Pipeline-Files-manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `readMavenPom` step from Pipeline Utility Steps (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readmavenpom-code-read-a-maven-project-file).